# Room reset database if key doesn't match

Tags: android, encryption, android-room

I use Room to store cache of my app. Also I encrypt database with key from Keystore and SqlCipher. In situations like restoring backup of app (i.e. via TitaniumBackup) or key being lost for whatever reason Room just crashes app. Any way to tell it to just delete old database if it can't be opened? It's just cache, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i have same problem in new version of room gradle but old version working fine for me.
currently i am using below version of room database.

```
 implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
 annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
```